# using SendGrid email service with the Azure SDK

Tags: sendgrid, azure-sdk-.net

I'm building an email service into my app, has anyone any experience using it with the Azure SDK to test it locally ? or is it only possible in an actual azure app ?

Answer (score 0):

> or is it only possible in an actual azure app ?

We could use SendGrid email service both for local and azure app. We could get more detail steps from Azure [official tutorials](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/sendgrid-dotnet-how-to-send-email#overview). The following is my test demo code

```
 var apiKey ="ApiKey";//System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("SENDGRID_APIKEY");
 var client = new SendGridClient(apiKey);
 var msg = new SendGridMessage()
 {
      From = new EmailAddress("x@example.com", "Send Grid"),
      Subject = "Hello World from the SendGrid CSharp SDK!",
      PlainTextContent = "Hello, Email!",
      HtmlContent = "<strong>Hello, Email!</strong>"
 };
 msg.AddTo(new EmailAddress("y@example.com", "Test User"));
 client.SendEmailAsync(msg).Wait();
```